# Word for benevolence but with a desire to also be self servingly sadistic

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

Is there a singular adjective or noun in English to describe a leader or ruler, who is both benevolent but also enjoys seeing their subjects suffer?  I. E.  In a video game like "The Sims", the player not only enjoys making the sims happy, but also enjoys the game as circumstances make life hard/bad for the sims.  I want to find a word that describes a person or being that enjoys the suffering as much as the joy when observing it from an outside perspective?

Comment: This sounds to me like an idea that requires more than one word to convey, at least in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [***ambivalent***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambivalent):

> having or showing simultaneous and contradictory attitudes or feelings toward something or someone
>
> *Americans are deeply **ambivalent** about the country's foreign role. Isolationist yearnings coexist uneasily with superpower policies*

[MW]

Answer (score 1):

> ## [Despot](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/despot)
>
> A ruler or other person who holds absolute power, typically one who exercises it in a cruel or oppressive way.

or

> ## [Autocrat](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/autocrat)
>
> an absolute ruler, especially a monarch who holds and exercises the powers of government as by inherent right, not subject to restrictions.
>   a person invested with or claiming to exercise absolute authority.
>   a person who behaves in an authoritarian manner; a domineering person.